# Table not getting created in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying but failing to create a table using Eclipse. 
What can I do to fix this?

```
PreparedStatement create=conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
stud(id int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
    firstname varchar(25), 
    lastname varchar(25)");
```

error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[IF NOT EXISTS] stud(id int unsigned not null auto_increment, firstname varchar(' at line 1

Comment: You're missing a close brace `)` at the end of your query

Comment: @gabe3886: a close brace is normally `}` — I think you mean close bracket `)` or close parenthesis (bracket being English, parenthesis more American).  But your diagnosis of the missing `)` is spot on.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler I get them mixed up from time to time, so I always try to give an example.  I'll make my comment an answer so it's easier for people to read

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your query for the table creation is missing a close bracket at the end, which makes the query syntactically invalid.  The query should be:

```
PreparedStatement create=conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
stud(id int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
    firstname varchar(25), 
    lastname varchar(25))");
```

In my opinion, code formatting so brackets/braces and other general syntax can line up help to avoid these situations as you can see the opens and closes lining up:

```
PreparedStatement create=conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
stud(
        id int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
        firstname varchar(25), 
        lastname varchar(25)
    )");
```

However, some coding guidelines might not allow you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Although everybody is picking the missing parenthesis up, however, the error message does not relate to a missing parenthesis and ever answer and comment ignores what's in the error message.

I belive that the OP did not copy the exact code that is being executed because the error message says:

> ...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**[IF NOT EXISTS]**

Note that in the error message the if not exists clause is enclosed by square brackets as in the mysql manual on [create table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html). In the manual it indicates that this clause is optional, but in the real life code the square brackets must not be there.

In the actual code there are no square brackets, this is why I belive that the OP did not copy the original code into the question. My answer is: remove the square brackets around the `if not exists` clause.

Comment: Interesting observation: the code shown doesn't match the error shown.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yep, this question is a mess and the OP is apparently not willing to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

It simply lacks a closing paranthesis, as far as I can tell.

```
PreparedStatement create=conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
stud(id int unsigned not null auto_increment, 
firstname varchar(25), 
lastname varchar(25))");
```